# Javascript Unrecognized Expression for single period

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm getting a console error "unrecognized expression: ." when this event occurs. It all works fine so I'm not sure what the deal is other than a syntax error. Any ideas?

```
 $(".home-focus__services__list").on('mouseover', 'a', function(){
    const aClass = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/);
    const serviceObjectPhoto = aClass.filter(function(e) { 
        return e.indexOf("service-") > -1;
    });
    $(".home-focus__services__photo").children("." + serviceObjectPhoto).css({
        'opacity': '1'
    }
```

I assume the error is in regards to

```
 .children("." + serviceObjectPhoto).css ///////
```

But I don't know how to solve the "problem".

Comment: um, serviceObjectPhoto is an array

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it is not true and false...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a class. You are using filter which will return an array of items that match. You could make yours work by referencing the first index of the array, but there is no reason to keep looking once you find the element.

You want to use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which will return the value that matches

```
const serviceObjectPhoto = aClass.find(function(e) { 
    return e.indexOf("service-") > -1;
});
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of assumptions in my answer.

But you can attach the event listener to any link with the class starting with `service`. Then set all photos as opacity 0, then use the class from the link to change the appropriate group of photos to have the opacity of 1.

```js
$(".home-focus__services__list").on('mouseover', 'a[class^=service]', function() {
  $(".home-focus__services__photo div[class^=service]").css({
    "opacity": 0
  });
  
  $(".home-focus__services__photo ." + $(this).prop("class")).css({
    'opacity': '1'
  });
});
```

```css
div[class^=service] {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-focus__services__list">
  <a class="service-1" href="">Service 1</a>
  <a class="service-2" href="">Service 2</a>
  <a class="service-3" href="">Service 3</a>
</div>

<div class="home-focus__services__photo">
  <div class="service-1">1</div>
  <div class="service-2">2</div>
  <div class="service-3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help!